# Different libraries with same initials, and a tag only refers to one of them

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I want to create a `gsl` tag to refer to the C++ Core Guidelines support Library (GSL). Unfortunately, there's also the GNU Scientific Library (GSL), and the existing tag refers to it.

What should I do? Use the same tag? Use a longer version of the time?

Please answer this question either about coinciding acronyms as tags, generally, or about this specific case.

Comment: Why would that tag be needed?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: It's a library which is likely to become increasingly useful/popular in the next few years at least. It's backed by key C++ language architects such as Stroustrup and Sutter. And it's likely questions will be asked about its use, applicability, maybe even different publishers' implementation of it etc.

Comment: When is enough popular to warrant a tag, we create it then, not before.

Comment: @Braiam: I have already seen [at least one C++ question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832090) that ought to have used such a tag. And all it takes to create a tag is to create one. The question of what it should be called is perfectly valid.

Comment: I suggest using [tag:c++-gsl]...

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm missing something, because I don't see any library mentioned *on the question* itself.

Comment: @Braiam: Right. Because the person in question didn't know where it came from. That doesn't mean it's not about the library. A question about Boost.Spirit is still a question about Boost.Spirit, even if you don't know its name.

Answer (score 1):

This particular case doesn't need a tag fighting for those letters, because a better one already exists for the topic:

- [cpp-core-guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpp-core-guidelines)

(You'll note that there is no the tag for the C++ Standard Library doesn't get used, because the various C++ language tags cover it.  If there get to be multiple implementations of the Core Guidelines Support Library, then there might be tags added for the variations, just as there are for specific C++ compilers with non-standard extensions and quirks.)

Comment: Ah, but there is one: [tag:c++-standard-library]. Or maybe that distinction should go to [tag:std] combined with [tag:c++]...? Not to forget, there's [tag:stl] which often gets confused with that...

Comment: @Deduplicator: 311 questions?  That tag effectively does not exist, and supports my point that there's no need for a distinct tag for the library portion of the C++ Core Guidelines.  No one can be expert in one without being expert in the other.

Comment: The guidelines and the GSL are not the same thing. You could ask about the guidelines but not the gsl.

Comment: Well, anyway, I concurr that cpp-core-guidelines is a good tag for that.

Answer (score 0):

Possible general solution:

- First conflicting acronym gets the general tag.
- Other conflicting acronyms need to use a prefix/suffix

In my case:

Like @Deduplicator suggests: Name the tag c++-gsl.

Comment: This is the right general approach, but not applicable here where there already is a tag.